# ggplot bar plot comparing multiple groups with a reference group

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
dat <- 
data.frame(keyId = rep(c('A','B','C','D'), times = 4),
group = rep(1:4, each = 4),
value = sample(1:100, 16))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = as.factor(keyId), y = as.factor(value))) + 
geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +  
facet_wrap(~group)
```

What I want to is:

```
temp1 <- dat %>% dplyr::filter(group %in% c(1, 4))
temp2 <- dat %>% dplyr::filter(group %in% c(2, 4))
temp3 <- dat %>% dplyr::filter(group %in% c(3, 4))

ggplot(temp1, aes(x = as.factor(keyId), y = value, fill = as.factor(group))) +
 geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')

ggplot(temp2, aes(x = as.factor(keyId), y = value, fill = as.factor(group))) +
 geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')

ggplot(temp3, aes(x = as.factor(keyId), y = value, fill = as.factor(group))) +
 geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')
```

i.e I want to plot bar plots comparing group 4 against group 1, 2, 3. I am trying to do this in a single panel using facet_wrap(~group). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a new *indicator* and then expand the data frame by group where each subset concatenates the 4th group with a *new_group* indicator.

Below uses base R methods: `ifelse` (for conditional assignment of *indicator* column), `by` (for grouping), `rbind` + `do.call` (for concatenating data frames), `transform` (to add *new_group* column), `subset` (to remove redundant row).

```
# ADD INDICATOR
dat$indicator <- factor(ifelse(dat$group == 4, 'control', 'treatment'))

# ITERATIVELY EXPAND BY GROUP
df_list <- by(dat, dat$group, function(sub)
  transform(rbind(sub, dat[dat$group == 4,]),
            new_group = sub$group[[1]])
)    
# BIND ALL DFs AND FILTER OUT 4 AND 4 PAIRINGS
graph_df <- subset(do.call(rbind, df_list), new_group != 4)

# PLOT USING fill AND LABEL CLEANUP
ggplot(graph_df, aes(x = as.factor(keyId), y = value, fill=indicator)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
  labs(title="Treatments vs Control Group", x="keyId") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position="bottom") +
  facet_wrap(~new_group)
```

[image: Plot Output]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something that makes this more complicated, but you can forgo the temporary data frames with a list, and just make one long data frame of all those subsets. If you give the list names, you can use that with the `.id` parameter of `dplyr::bind_rows`, and that becomes your faceting variable.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(keyId = rep(c('A','B','C','D'), times = 4),
             group = rep(1:4, each = 4),
             value = sample(1:100, 16))

dat_paired <- list(
  set1 = filter(dat, group %in% c(1, 4)),
  set2 = filter(dat, group %in% c(2, 4)),
  set3 = filter(dat, group %in% c(3, 4))
) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "set")

head(dat_paired)
#>    set keyId group value
#> 1 set1     A     1    21
#> 2 set1     B     1    57
#> 3 set1     C     1    66
#> 4 set1     D     1    33
#> 5 set1     A     4     1
#> 6 set1     B     4    32

ggplot(dat_paired, aes(x = as.factor(keyId), y = value, fill = as.factor(group))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(vars(set))
```

[image]

Also an aside: `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is the same as `geom_col()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`, where the values of group 4 are subtracted from the other 3 groups, then the differences are plotted.

```r
dat %>% filter(group==4) %>% select(-group,value.4=value) %>% 
  left_join(dat,.) %>% mutate(diff=value-value.4) %>% 
  filter(group!=4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(keyId,diff,fill=keyId)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  facet_wrap(~group) + theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  ylab('Difference of Group 4')
```

[image: bar graph]